# Combine change event and each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which is executed every time someone clicks on a checkbox, and depending on if the checkbox was checked or unchecked different things may happen. However, after form submission, the previous values are loaded and I wish to apply the same changes based on if the box is checked. This leaves me with two identical functions

Sample code:

```
// !- Bind checkboxes to show divs
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind("change", function(){
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#"+$(this).data('toggle')).show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#"+$(this).data('toggle')).hide();
                }
        });

        // Init checkboxes which are already checked via previous selection
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index){
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#"+$(this).data('toggle')).show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#"+$(this).data('toggle')).hide();
                }

        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ms7EY/

I know with bind, you could add multiple events, however the each function is not an event, and I'm not sure how to clean this up a bit. Am I forced to create a separate function and continue to use bind() and each() but use a callback for both or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger the event using [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), it will execute all the change event handler associated with the selected elements

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind("change", function(){
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#"+$(this).data('toggle')).show();
            }
            else {
                $("#"+$(this).data('toggle')).hide();
            }
    }).trigger('change'); //or .change()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zeBGP/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of each, you can "simulate" the change event with that :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('change')
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ms7EY/2/